# Не могу получить ссылку на ключ объекта в редюсере

Tags: reactjs, redux

Почему я не могу получить ссылку на ключ объекта? Хочу экшеном изменить title.

```
return {...state, dataFolder.title: action.payload};
```

когда пишу `state.dataFolder.title`тоже не работает

```
   const initialState = {
   windowForCreating: 0,
   dataFolder: {
       title: '',
       parent_id: ''
      },
   httpMethod: 'POST',
   url: 'api/auth/folder/{id}'
  };

const createFolderNoteReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_RECEIVE_NAME_FOLDER:
        return {...state, dataFolder.title: action.payload};
    case ACTION_OPEN_WINDOW_TO_CREATE:
        return {...state, windowForCreating: action.payload};
    case ACTION_CLOSED_WINDOW:
        return {...state, windowForCreating: action.payload};
    default:
        return state
      }
};

export default createFolderNoteReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const initialState = {
  windowForCreating: 0,
  dataFolder: {
    title: "",
    parent_id: ""
  },
  httpMethod: "POST",
  url: "api/auth/folder/{id}"
};

const createFolderNoteReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_RECEIVE_NAME_FOLDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        dataFolder: {
          ...dataFolder,
          title: action.payload
        }
      };
    case ACTION_OPEN_WINDOW_TO_CREATE:
      return { ...state, windowForCreating: action.payload };
    case ACTION_CLOSED_WINDOW:
      return { ...state, windowForCreating: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default createFolderNoteReducer;
```